# TestComplete cannot find an object by 2 properties

Tags: testcomplete

I have a problem with how TestComplete finds objects by two properties

I find all objects by some property 1 and value 1, then select those having property 2 equal to value 2, get 6 objects

Then I find all objects by property 2 and value 2, then select those having property 1 equal to value 1, again get 6 objects

Then pass to FindAll both properties and get zero objects

```
var p1 = "NewActionList"
var p2 = "titleBar"


var x1 = Sys["FindAll"](["NativeSlObject.Parent.Name.OleValue"], [p1], 100)
var x2 = Sys["FindAll"](["Parent.NativeSlObject.Parent.Parent.Name.OleValue"], [p2], 100)

x1 = new VBArray(x1).toArray()
x2 = new VBArray(x2).toArray()

for (var i = 0; i < x1.length; i++)
{
  if (x1[i].Parent.NativeSlObject.Parent.Parent.Name.OleValue == p2)
  {
    Log["Message"]("x1")
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < x2.length; i++)
{
  if (x2[i].NativeSlObject.Parent.Name.OleValue == p1)
  {
    Log["Message"]("x2")
  }
}

var x = Sys["FindAll"](["NativeSlObject.Parent.Name.OleValue", "Parent.NativeSlObject.Parent.Parent.Name.OleValue"], [p1, p2], 100)
x = new VBArray(x).toArray()
Log["Message"](x.length)
```

Get x1 six times, x2 six times, and 0

Answer (score 0):

FindAll is searching for one object which will have both parameters you specified:
*ativeSlObject.Parent.Name.OleValue = p1*

and 
*Parent.NativeSlObject.Parent.Parent.Name.OleValue = p2*

Do you have the object with such properties in the object tree?

Comment: Yes. I verified this in object tree. Also in my code that is cited in the question I verify this by finding all objects having NativeSlObject.Parent.Name.OleValue = p1 and checking that among them there are objects having Parent.NativeSlObject.Parent.Parent.Name.OleValue = p2

Comment: The sought for object should have _both_ properties - p1 and p2. The method won't work if one parent object has p1 and the child has p2.

Answer (score 0):

I think that such search can be rather slow even if it works. I recommend that you search for the desired objects in several steps using a simpler search criteria.

Also, you can find it easier to use the Name Mapping functionality along with its [Required Children](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/56656/) and [Extended Find](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/55674/) features.